# Update Total Val. in Item overview

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I have added a new condition type and using transaction ME53N, I am able to get the **Net value** in condition screen and **Total Val.** In item overview.

[image]

[image]

I am using **BAPI_PR_CREATE** to create PR and created an enhancement ( class CL_DB_SERVICE_PACKAGE_MMSRV method POST_CONDITIONS ) to update the condition and the Total val. In Item overview screen by setting the variable **MY_EXT_HEADER-net_value** to the calculated value.
However, I am not able to set the **Total Val.** with my calculated value. Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Any method or function module to update Item Overview Total Val. in the method POST_CONDITIONS?

Comment: ME53N is a display transaction. Why are you writing enhancement in post_conditions?

Comment: Actually i am using a webservice which call the BAPI_PR_CREATE which in turn call the method POST_CONDITION. In this method, my enhancement update the required value like Net Value based on the calculation of the new condition created. It is working fine, all value are updated as expected. Only the Net_Value in Item overview is not updating.

Comment: can update question with some code of BAPI_PR_CREATE call and POST_CONDITION?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manage to solve it by creating another enhancement in lcl_req_header